# Super user in linux should not see my file because it contain password

Tags: linux

I have script which is having user name and password in it.
How to make that file not read/write by super user sudo.
I am not linux team as script in common linux server.Linux team are able to access that file.
Anyway we can use LDAP user can access that file or to access that file any user & pass setup something.

Comment: Encryption is your only hope. Note that the server administrators can also look at process memory if they so choose, so your best hope if you want to keep them from seeing something is to never have it on their server.

Comment: Encryption we tried But Superuser are able to decrypt it.We call it as Jump server which used to run script.If you suggest any encrytion that is only visible to my creditials that would be great.

Comment: As I said, if you don't want superuser to see your file, don't give it to them by putting it on their machine. For something to be of use to you on their machine, it needs to be in a form that they can read. End of story. I'm done here.

Comment: Why didn't your encryption attempt work? Even if the admins recorded you entering a regular password, they could do nothing to decrypt public key encryption, as long as you don't use the private key on the compromised server.

Answer (score 1):

> How to make that file not read/write by super user sudo.

You cannot. That's what 'super user' *means*: the highest-level administrator account which can perform all actions and bypass all security checks.

If you don't trust your own servers' admin team, this is first a management issue, not a technical one.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated, a particularly knowledgeable and dedicated root admin could bypass any mechanism in place. I'm assuming, however, that you are referring to "opportunistic" access.

I expect that the encryption you were doing was block/filesystem based, which makes it easy enough for the administrator to see the file in the filesystem while its mounted.

You need single FILE or smaller level encryption - something which does not mount the encrypted data onto the filesystem. Something like a keepass database or file edited in vi with AES encryption. You would only open the file for the time its needed.

In order to get this the admin would need to dump the memory while the file is in ram or displayed, or to trojan the software used to open it definitely doable but more work/less obvious then a single file.  You may be able to further frustrate admin efforts by creative use of secondary encryption NOT on the computer, eg. a secondary encryption/decryption translation you apply from your brain, eg. subtracting 3 digits from each number,  changing letters like a_c, b_d etc, reversing text, changing case etc (but don't overestimate the strength of such a scheme).